# (Reduced) Topological complexity of (even) spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology

i was wondering why the (reduced) topological complexity of all spheres isn't 1. So first of all, the definition of the (reduced) topological complexity i have is the following:

The (reduced) topological complexity of a space $X$ is the minimal nummber $n$ such that there exist $n+1$ open subsets of $X$ which cover $X$ such that on each of these subsets exists a section of the free path space fibration $\pi_X: PX \rightarrow X \times X, \gamma \mapsto (\gamma (0), \gamma (1))$.

Now the argument i was thinking of is to take two different points $a, b$ on a sphere $S^n$ and consider the open subsets $S^n - \{ a \}$ and $S^n - \{ b \}$. These are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a global section: $s: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow P\mathbb{R}^n, (a, b) \mapsto \gamma_{a, b}$ where $\gamma_{a, b}: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, t \mapsto (1-t)a+tb$. So let $h: S^n – \{ a \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a homeomorphism. Then $h_{\text{ind}}^{-1} \circ s \circ (h \times h)$, where $h_{\text{ind}}$ is the induced hoemeomorphism from $PS^n$ to $P\mathbb{R}^n$ (which i think should exist), is the desired local section of $\pi_{S^n}$ on $S^n - \{ a \} \times S^n - \{ a \}$.
Now do the same with the other point. So we only need two subsets and therefore the (reduced) topological complexity of a sphere is 1.

Where is my mistake since i have read that the (reduced) topological complexity of even spheres is 2?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, let me adress your comments and edit my question. But i think my underlying question is still valid.

Comment: Oh, i see. I guess i am missing $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$. Thank you. But i guess this proof can show (if i add a third subset) that $TC(S^n) \le 2$, which admittedly isn't such a remarkable  statement.

Comment: whoops, commented before i saw your edit. Okay, yes thanks a lot. Concerning the $n+1$, thats why i wrote reduced now, however i read some papers where i got the impression that most people now use the reduced version. And i think your statement in the brackets should be without the "not".

Comment: btw, if you want to write an answer i can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets fix your definition. We start with a topological space $X$ and the projection $\pi:PX\to X\times X$, $\pi(\lambda)=\big(\lambda(0),\lambda(1)\big)$

> **Definition.** [The topological complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_complexity) of $X$ is a the smallest natural number $n$ such that:
>
> 1. There is an open covering $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $X\times X$;
> 2. For any $i$ there is a local section $s_i:U_i\to PX$ of $\pi$
>
> We denote the topological complexity of $X$ by $TC(X)$.

I'm not sure what "reduced topological complexity" is (I've never seen that term before), your definition seems to only subtract $1$ from the topological complexity defined above. I will denote your reduced topological complexity by $TC_r(X)$.

> Where is my mistake since i have read that the (reduced) topological complexity of even spheres is 2?

You've defined $U(x)=\big(S^m\backslash\{x\}\big)\times\big(S^m\backslash\{x\}\big)$. You are correct that there are local sections on $U(a)$ and $U(b)$, however $\big\{U(a),U(b)\big\}$ is not a covering of $S^m\times S^m$. Both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ points don't belong to either. You can fix that by adding the third $U(c)$ but now you endup with $3$ subsets, which shows that $TC(S^m)\leq 3$ (or equivalently $TC_r(X)\leq 2$). You are yet to show that such covering is minimal. It is if $m$ is even, but unfortunately it is not when $m$ is odd.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think people use the reduced version only so that for contractible spaces the topological complexity is 0, meaning that $TC$ of something with homotopy type of a point (which i guess can kind of be seen as the neutral element in homotopy theory) gets mapped to the neutral element of addition (aka 0).